# how to replace NAs resulting from joining tables using data.table in r

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have 2 data sets:

```
a <- data.table(Sex = c("male", "female"), Age = sample(c(10,20,30), 100, replace = T), 
                Survived = sample(0:1, 100, replace = T))[, ID := .I]

b <- data.table(Sex = c("male", "female"), Age = sample(c(10,20,40), 100, replace = T), 
                Survived = sample(0:1, 100, replace = T))[, ID := .I]
```

Then, I created a third dataset props:

```
props <- a[, list(.N, percentSurvived = mean(Survived)), keyby = list(Sex, Age)]
props[, Prediction := as.integer(percentSurvived > 0.5 )]
```

When I join them , I get NAs in some rows of percentSurvived because "b" has some ages that "a" does not:

```
b[props, Prediction := i.Prediction, on = c("Sex", "Age")]
```

I want to take the resulting NAs and get a Prediction value based on maching varialbles. I tried this (subsetting the NAs and joining on Sex only):

```
b[is.na(Prediction)][props, Prediction := i.Prediction, on = c("Sex" )]
```

but I still have NAs

```
      Sex Age Survived  ID Prediction
  1:   male  40        1   1         NA
  2: female  40        1   2         NA
  3:   male  20        0   3          1
  4: female  20        0   4          0
```

Comment: thanks @Frank,  cut/paste error

Comment: You have the statistical question of how to fill in the prediction for age 40 considering you don't have such a prediction in props. If you decide to fill it with the nearest age, the answer is `b[, Prediction := props[b, x.Prediction, on = c("Sex", "Age"), roll="nearest"]]` (yeah, kind of convoluted).